# Google Data Shared Contact sync from server side app

Tags: .net, google-api, google-contacts-api

We are trying to create a server side process that could sync some internal data sources with Google Shared Contacts (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts/).
The problem we have is that it seems there's no option for use to preauthenticate the calls. Here seems the only option is to have the OAuth flow where the user needs to explicitely give the ok the google request.

For the Directory API we've been able to use this approach https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#create_the_service_account_and_its_credentials but this does't seem to be available for the Contacts API.

So the question is how can we create a server side sync process (in .NET) that doesn't use the client OAuth flow.

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening every time you want to make a request to the contacts api? or is it only the first time?

If your app didn't have this scope and now you are adding it, then it needs to be granted.

Comment: Not sure I follow you here. My problem is that we don't seem to be able to make that kind of calls "server side", without the user participation.

Comment: Did you add this scope recently? Did you add the scope in the Marketplace SDK? Did the user grant your app to use this scope? The domain admin granted permission for this new scope? i'm trying to understand if its related to the configuration or if it could be other issue